# Why is :not(p) selecting paragraphs?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```css
:not(p) {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<div>This is some text in a div element.</div>

<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Link to W3Schools!</a>
```

The `not(selector)` is used to select every element that is not specified element, So in the above code i am getting red color on both `p` which is a non-selected item.

I am expecting only `div`,`a`,`h1` to be red, not `p` as `p` is a specified element and it is meant to be leave and style have to apply to all others element?

Comment: I don't have an explanation, but `body :not(p)` seems to work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not?retiredLocale=de#description has some other examples that might be useful.

Comment: @Junaid, do you have any reference for your first statement? What makes you say so?

Comment: @Junaid It doesn't work as expected. It is a good question actually.

Answer (score 6):

The selector `:not(p)` will select *all* elements that are not `p` elements: This includes `html` and `body`. We are setting `color` on both these elements.

Additionally, the [property `color` is inherited by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color#formal_definition).

With `color` being inherited by default and us setting `color` on `body` to red, the `p` elements will inherit the value red for `color` from their parent, namely `body`.

---

You could select only children of `body`, meaning the *de facto* browser-default black for `body`'s `color` will be inherited by the `p` elements, while all other children that are not `p` elements will have `color` set to red.

**Note**: With selector `body :not(p)`, only children of `body` will have `color` evaluate to black. Other elements will have `color` set to red, which indirect `p` descendants  of `body` will inherit.

But the easiest way for `p` elements to have a certain `color` is to set it (instead of inheriting it).

Comment: And when using your developer tools to debug, make sure to check the computed tab as it will tell you where the element's color is coming from

Answer (score 1):

For the visual explanation from the browser, we can see that the color for both of our `<p>` elements is being inherited from the `body` element.

And we are setting our CSS as follows:

```
:not(p) {
   color: #ff0000;
}
```

Which means all the elements apart from the p element will have a color set to red, which includes the `body` element which seems to be the immediate parent for the `p` in our case. And that is from where the `p` inherits in this case.
Had there been any parent for p elements, then it would have inherited from there. [Image-2]

Hope this helps more to visualize.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specifically target the p elements for a different color, you can directly target them like this:

```
p {
color: blue;
```

}

If you want to target p elements that are directly inside the body, you can use:

```
body p {
color: blue; /* or any color you prefer */
```

Answer (score -1):

The `:not` selector doesn't work like that. Before the `:not` selector you should tell from which parent do you want to select.

`body :not(p)` targets all elements that are not paragraph elements within the  of the HTML document and applies a red color (#ff0000) to their text.

```css
body :not(p) {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<body>
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<div>This is some text in a div element.</div>
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Link to W3Schools!</a>
</body>
```

Comment: While true, this doesn't answer the question, which is _why_.